# Guice expert question

Tags: java, guice

I am wondering if someone would be such an expert in guice that he even would know how to implement that :

I have an injection annotation (`@ConfParam`)with some parameters , like that :

```
class TestClass {

private final int intValue;

    @Inject
    public TestClass(@ConfParam(section = "test1", key = "1") int intValue{
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

}
```

The ConfParam is my custom annotation.

Now , when the injection value is requested , I would like guice to create a dynamic binding, to resolve the value.

For that binding I will need the parameters inside the annotation.

Some example could be , I will have to look in the database in some table where the section is ? and the key is ?.

All the trouble is that the data is not available when the injector is created and could be also be added at runtime.

Ps.
I static solution is easy. ( just have a look at the [Names](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/name/Names.html) class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [CustomInjections](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections) as a starting point. I have done something similar before that used a parameter to customize a logger further than simply the class name.